# Best way to find the encoding of an old binary file (and to decode it)?

Tags: hex, binaryfiles

I have been asked by a library to recover some metadata records from some very old (early 1990s) files that can no longer be read by any software and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for finding out how they are encoded? Here is an arbitrary snippet of one of them:

```
0014 9c36 0021 7073 2332 0000 0014 9c4d
0022 3478 2332 0000 0014 9c64 0021 7074
2332 0000 0014 9c7b 0022 3479 2332 0000
0014 a3c1 002a edab 2330 0000 0014 a3d8
0022 347a 2332 0000 0014 a3ef 0022 347b
2332 0000 0014 a406 0022 53e9 2332 0000
0014 a41d 0022 347c 2332 0000 0014 a434
0021 87f9 2332 0000 0014 a44b 0020 f046
2332 0000 0014 a462 0027 f928 2332 0000
0014 a479 0020 9e45 2332 0000 0014 a490
0027 68d3 2330 0000 0014 a4a7 0022 44b8
2332 0000 0014 a4be 0027 cf6b 2330 0000
```

So it is hex of some sort, but I can't seem to decode it to make it make sense. Does anyone have any ideas where I might start? I would preferably like to write a Python script to turn them into some structured metadata format but first I will need to get at something that looks like ASCII perhaps?

Many thanks in advance!

Adam

Comment: You can run the files through something like `hexdump -C` to see if they contain any interesting patterns. That'll only get you so far, though. There is some structure in the snippet that you pasted (repeated 0000 0014 followed by two bytes that increase by 23 each time, for instance), but going from that to an actual understanding of the format is a pretty tough task.

Comment: Thanks - it helps a little. I can see lots of square brackets from one of the files. The only example I have of some data not encoded (that was given to me) is this (not for the fragment in the post)...

[0000001006]FORT VALLEY BLUES]]]]]]Sleeve title]]]

Comment: And in one of the hexdump prints I get some things like... .[U%......[U&...
..[U&.....[U&...
...U2I.....U2I..
...U2I......2[].